# PSConsoleReadLine exceptions

Tags: powershell, windows-10, psreadline

'PSReadLine' cmdlets no longer work:

```
PS> Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Vi
Set-PSReadlineOption : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine' threw an exception.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Vi
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-PSReadlineOption], TypeInitializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetPSReadlineOption

PS> Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine' threw an exception.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler], TypeInitializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetPSReadLineKeyHandlerCommand
```

Yesterday, I received this Update: [June 12, 2018—KB4284835 (OS Build 17134.112)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4284835/windows-10-update-kb4284835). Before this, I'd never had any problems with `PSReadLine`, and I really need it to be working...

- `PSVersion 5.1.17134.112`
- `Windows 10 Home Version 1803 OS Build 17134.112`

Comment: Start from `$Error[0] | fl -Force`

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in the Windows 10 October Update, and can be resolved with a [patch](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/lzybkr/PSReadLine/branch/master/artifacts) as discussed in [this Github thread](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/614).